# How to access variables from a function inside executed inside another function?

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I am refactoring my https://github.com/perdugames/cacau test library, which I did to learn a bit more about JavaScript and testing. The problem is that I'm not liking how FIXTURE are currently working on it, so I decided to refactor, and I wanted to get the result below, but I still do not know how to make the "addTest" functions have access to "x".

```
const runner = new Runner();

runner.addSuite(() => {
    console.log('Suite 1');

    runner.addFixture(() => {
        console.log('Suite');
        const x = 10;
    });


    runner.addTest(() => {
        console.log('Test 1');
        console.log(x);
    });

    runner.addTest(() => {
        console.log('Test 2');
        console.log(x);
    });

});

runner.run();
```

*Note: Of course without the use of globals, and without adding to the scope of "runner".*

Comment: You can define it in `obj`'s scope i.e. `obj.x`

Comment: You can declare it in `funcA`'s scope, it's not technically considered global if it's within the parent's scope.

Comment: @Satpal I updated the note, in the scope of "object" also would not.

Comment: Your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense. A variable or constant declared in a scope cannot be accessed outside that cope. That's the point of scopes. Your code is so abstract that it is impossible to tell what problem you are really trying to solve.

Comment: @Rewire Maybe, let me try. But "x" being in the scope of "funcA", will the functions "funcA2A" and "funcA2B" have access to "x"?

Comment: @PerduGames My bad I just noticed you are appending functions to the original object, so basically `obj.x` should work, but just letting you know this isn't "good" code there are better/correct ways to write this section

Comment: @Rewire But it(obj.x) would not work for my case, and there's a reason I want to do this, I've tried it some other way, it did not work as expected, I see the way is here.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you should be using contexts. Please read more about contexts in javascript. There's plenty of sites.

In your case you can call a context

```
obj.funcA(() => {
    let ctx = this;
    console.log('A');

    obj.funcA1(() => {
        let ctxFncA1 = this // context of previous level... etc.
        console.log('A1');
        const x = 10;
    });

    // ... you get the point.    
});
```

In general what you're trying to do is not "ok". If you go build object class, the JavaScript language might allow you to do really anything, but you must not.

Probably you should look into object programmation in JavaScript (book or training website).

Actually you have an example describing pretty much what you desire on : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let (Code is copy/pasted from there.)

```
var Thing;

{
  let privateScope = new WeakMap();
  let counter = 0;

  Thing = function() {
    this.someProperty = 'foo';

    privateScope.set(this, {
      hidden: ++counter,
    });
  };

  Thing.prototype.showPublic = function() {
    return this.someProperty;
  };

  Thing.prototype.showPrivate = function() {
    return privateScope.get(this).hidden;
  };
}

console.log(typeof privateScope);
// "undefined"

var thing = new Thing();

console.log(thing);
// Thing {someProperty: "foo"}

thing.showPublic();
// "foo"

thing.showPrivate();
// 1
```

Comment: I think you showed me the way, I just did not know the name of what to study, I will study.

Comment: scope or context are the keywords you need to look for. Here's a good place to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference

Comment: There's a reason I do this, I study JavaScript by creating stuff, and I'm refactoring a test library I did a while back, here it is: https://github.com/perdugames/cacau. I did not want to talk about it, because you'll see many comments like "why do not you use an existing one? ..." I got tired of it already, I'm doing it to learn, because I like to learn how things work.

Comment: I updated the question with the real problem. Now I'll study what you gave me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is physically possible. You would have to pass the the variable to the function in order to access it if you do not want a global variable, or have it accessible in the scope of a class or object.

While this variable should be in your heap, there is no way to communicate its address to the scope of the new function without passing something to it, either a pointer or the value itself.

Comment: Yes, but I could pass a pointer or its own value, I just do not know the correct way to do it, yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to resolve the issue, the first was:

```
function test(){  
    console.log(this.x * 2);
}
function fixture() {
    this.x = 5;
}
test.call(new fixture()) // 10
```

This is the worst way I found, since I will always have to use "this", and I will still have to deal with FIXTURE as a constructor function, otherwise it would be better to use a literal object in this case.

The second way I chose it is simpler, and it already fits in with what I have ready:

```
const runner = new Runner();

runner.addSuite(() => {
    console.log('Suite 1');
    var x;
    runner.addFixture(() => {
        console.log('Suite');
        x = 1;
        x++;
    });
    runner.addTest(() => {
        console.log('Test 1');
        console.log(x); // 2
    });

    runner.addTest(() => {
        console.log('Test 2');
        console.log(x); // 2
    });

});
```